# E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, dart

I'm having problems with E-mail authentication with firebase.I dont know how to fix it ive tried many online suggestions but none of them seem to work so i am kind of stuck in this thing

Code-

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/main.dart';





class Body extends StatefulWidget {


@override
_BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
} 

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();




@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Size size = MediaQuery
    .of(context)
    .size;
return Background(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "SIGNUP",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
          SvgPicture.asset(
            "assets/icons/signup.svg",
            height: size.height * 0.35,
          ),

          RoundedInputField(
            hintText: "Your Email",
            onChanged: (val) {
            },
          ),
          RoundedPasswordField(
            onChanged: (val) {
            },
          ),
          RoundedButton(
              text: "SIGNUP",
              press: ()
              async {
                try {
                  FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
                      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                    email: _emailController.text,
                    password: _passwordController.text,)).user;
                  if(user != null){
                    UserUpdateInfo updateUser = UserUpdateInfo();
                    user.updateProfile(updateUser);
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.menu);
                  }
                } catch (e) {
                  print(e);
                  _passwordController.text = "";
                  _emailController.text = "";
                  // TODO: alertdialog with error
                }
              },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
          AlreadyHaveAnAccountCheck(
            login: false,
            press: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return LoginScreen();
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          OrDivider(),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SocalIcon(
                iconSrc: "assets/icons/fbb.svg",
                press: () => signUpWithFacebook(),
              ),
              SocalIcon(
                iconSrc: "assets/icons/twitterr.svg",
                press: () {},
              ),
              SocalIcon(
                iconSrc: "assets/icons/google.svg",
                press: () => _signIn(context),
                ),
                ],
                )
                ],
                ),
                ),
                ),
                );
                }
```

Rounded input field--

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 
'package:flutter_auth/login_Signup/components/text_field_container.dart';
 import 'package:flutter_auth/constants.dart';
Import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 
'package:flutter_auth/login_Signup/Screens/Signup/components/body.dart';

class RoundedInputField extends StatefulWidget {


final String hintText;
 final IconData icon;
final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
const RoundedInputField({
Key key,
this.hintText,
this.icon = Icons.person,
this.onChanged,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return TextFieldContainer(
  child: TextFormField(
    controller: _emailController,
    onChanged: widget.onChanged,
    cursorColor: kPrimaryColor,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      icon: Icon(
        widget.icon,
        color: kPrimaryColor,
      ),
      hintText: widget.hintText,
      border: InputBorder.none,
    ),
  ),
  );
  }
  }
```

My Debug Console!!--

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707): Failed to handle 
method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707): 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):                        
at 
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.1:5)
    E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at 
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.2:288)
   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):     at 
io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.handleCreateUserWithEmailAndPa 
   ssword(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:361)
   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):     at 
io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:143)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:230)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/flutter (16707): PlatformException(error, Given String is empty or null, null)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.1:5)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.2:288)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.handleCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:361)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:143)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:230)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(16707):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/flutter (16707): PlatformException(error, Given String is empty or null, null)
```

It seems like im putting an empty string somewhere but i cant seem to figure out where I have a feeling its because of the custom textfield i added or something like that. any kind of help would be appreciated!!

Comment: You need to bind the TextEditingControllers to your input fields. You may at least show one of the RoundedInputField widget code so you can be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I've added the input field

Comment: @HelpMeGetGood Have you tried the answer?

Comment: yes heres the updated version of it still got the error

Comment: there I added the text form field.Still am getting the error.

Comment: hello.can u help me i added your answer still didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                    email: _emailController.text,
                    password: _passwordController.text,)
```

the `email` and `password` inside this method are both null. you have to use a `TextFormField` and bind the controller to it, and then you can access the `text`, example:

```
        body: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: emailController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Email Address",
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Enter Email Address';
                    }
                    else if(!value.contains('@')){
                      return 'Please enter a valid email address!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: passwordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Password",
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Enter Password';
                    } else if (value.length < 6) {
                      return 'Password must be atleast 6 characters!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Check the docs:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#2-use-a-texteditingcontroller